# How can only part of the executed command be displayed in the plot?

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:1:6
    scatter(BC(:,6),BC(:,i))
    lft=LinearModel.fit(BC(:,6),BC(:,i))
    plot(lft)
end
```

When I use the linear fit model, I get the following output:

```
Linear regression model:
y ~ 1 + x1

Estimated Coefficients:
               Estimate      SE    tStat    pValue
(Intercept)    6.1593e-15    0     Inf      0     
x1             1.14    0     Inf      0     

Number of observations: 569, Error degrees of freedom: 567
Root Mean Squared Error: 2.23
R-squared: 0.917,  Adjusted R-Squared 1
F-statistic vs. constant model: Inf, p-value = 0
```

Out of all these calculated parameters, I want only RMSE and R^2,for example, (or any sub-information) to be displayed in the plot.

How can only part of the executed command be displayed in the plot?

I would really appreciate your help. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this output produced by the `plot(lft)` command? Or is this the regular on-screen output from calling [`lft=LinearModel.fit(BC(:,6),BC(:,i))`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.fit.html) without `:` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

`LinearModel.fit` returns an [object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.fit.html#outputarg_mdl). In your example, this would be the variable `lft`.
[The properties and methods are listed in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel-class.html).
If, for example, you wanted only the RMSE for each of the 6 fits you perform, you could consider the following quick approach:

```
for i=1:1:6
    lft=LinearModel.fit(BC(:,6),BC(:,1));
    RMSE(i) = lft.RMSE;
end
plot(RMSE)
```

Here, you access the RMSE of the linear fit from the object: `lft.RMSE`. However, you will need to store that value from each fit/loop iteration. That way, you can plot all the RMSEs.

---

The block of output you cite in your question, starting with

```
Linear regression model:
y ~ 1 + x1

...
```

is the command line output of calling `LinearModel.fit` - if you do not want that to appear, just add a `;` to the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the answer. :)